# How to combine two timelines in tableau

Tags: pandas, tableau-desktop

[image]

I'm playing around with Tableau exploring UK unemployment data. I've used Pandas to load in data for unemployment over time for men and women and plotted it over time, but can't work out out to put both charts on same to show the absolute difference in unemployment count.

I can do this in Pandas:
[image]

But not sure in Tableau.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen multiple approaches towards this problem.

refer this article : [here](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/combining-start-and-end-dates-into-a-single-axis)

My issue was resolved using the LoD method

```
MIN(
    IF DATETRUNC('month', [Order Date]) = DATETRUNC('month', [Ship Date])
    THEN { FIXED DATETRUNC('month', [Ship Date]) : COUNTD([Order ID]) }
    END
)
```

Unfortunately I cannot share the workbook now, however, I found this article useful.